# Database schema changes - Db2

Tags: java, database, db2, schema

Is there a way to identify the following using Java for DB2?

1. New columns added to the table
2. Columns that are renamed in the table
3. Columns that are deleted in the table

Would the above 3 be possible for the view as well?

Comment: How do you distinguish between a renamed column and a column deleted & added?

Comment: Exactly the same in my mind, hence the question to see if there are system tables that can help.

Comment: I believe there is no history on columns.  Impossible at this time.

Comment: You would need to go through the transaction logs. They are documented, but not the level you want...

Comment: What flavor of DB2? At least one flavor has most of the info available as long as the tables are journaled, but the info should always be part of the question regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Java programs can easily query DB2 to obtain the current definitions of views, tables, and columns (by reading the corresponding `SYSCAT` views), but DB2 does not automatically maintain an audit trail of DDL changes. Your Java program would need to connect to the database at some regular interval, execute queries to capture the full set of object definitions it cares about, and then compare the results against definitions from a prior run in order to see if anything important has changed. If you decide to go with this approach, I recommend using `ORDER BY` in your queries to enforce a consistent sorting order in the result sets you'll be comparing.

Instead of using hand-rolled SQL to pull the object definitions out of the system catalog views, you may want to consider using the `db2look` utility, which can reverse-engineer a live database (or parts of one) into a DDL script. The trade-off is that `db2look` cannot be run from a JDBC connection; the command uses an executable that can only be run on the local DB2 server or from a remote system via DB2's Data Server Client (full or runtime).